# Can't run Passenger Standalone in RVM Mixed Mode. It keeps telling me I need to update my RVM Wrappers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger

I've just installed the latest RVM on my new server using Mixed Mode, and in my user account, I ran `rvm user all` to give my user a completely separate ruby environment -- no sharing of rubies or gems.

I installed the passenger gem and when I tried to run `passenger start`, it told me this:

```
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old. Please update them first by running 'rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all'.
```

So I ran the command it listed: `rvm update --head && rvm reload && rvm repair all`

Ran `passenger start` and it gave mteh same error as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have old installation of RVM, we do not have that message in our code base anymore, can you update RVM first:

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
rvm get stable
```